# How to get a column value from a temporary Datatable (.net) based on a condtion

Tags: asp.net

```
ID  name   folderpath        files 

1    S1    D:\Official\1     1.jpg;2.jpg
2    S2    D:\Official\2    3.jpg;4.jpg
```

This is my Temp Datatable. From this I want to get the files(Eg : 1.jpg;2.jpg) by giving input as folderpath (Eg:D:\Official\1).

Please help..
Regards
Jithesh

Comment: You need to clarify this question. Are you talking about of a NET object DataTable or are you talking of a datatable in a database? And in this latest case, what is the database?

Comment: its .net object datatable. and I am using sql server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the index of column you want to fetch then you can do this:-

```
dt.Rows[rowIndex][columnName];
```

Otherwise, since DataTable is a collection of datarow elements you can iterate it using a `foreach` loop like this:-

```
string files = String.Empty;
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    if(row["folderpath"].ToString() == "YourValue")
    {  
         files= row["files"].ToString();
         break;
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

If dataTable may contain duplicate rows then you can use, LINQ to query your table like this:-

```
var allfiles = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>("folderPath") == searchVal)
                                .Select(x => x.Field<string>("files"));
```

Comment: And if there are multiple rows than ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `DataTable.Select()` method:

```
DataRow[] foundRows = myDataTable.Select("[folderpath] = 'D:\Official\1'");
for(int i = 0; i < foundRows.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(foundRows[i]["files"]);
    // Or do something else with it
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var filteredData = dt.Select("folderpath like '%Official\1%'");
```

This will return array of datarow if data is found.